# How did Gothic differ from Baroque architecture?

Tags: architecture

Source: [*Art Theory For Beginners*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934389471), p. 29 Bottom.

> Gothic architecture is all big cathedrals, with pointed arches, and flying 
>   buttresses, supporting intricate sculptures and beautiful decoration. Based 
>   on sophisticated engineering, the building's skeleton could house huge 
>   stained glass windows. Abbot Suger 1081—1155 described in detail the 
>   improvements he made to the French cathedral of St. Denis (one of the first 
>   Gothic cathedrals). He stuffed his building full of precious materials and 
>   artworks, symbolising "divine radiance," and thought that the new stained 
>   glass windows reflected the "light of God." In painting and sculpture a very 
>   elegant, colorful, and decorative, religious art developed at the end of this 
>   period, which is known as **International Gothic**.

Doesn't the first sentence overhead fit [Baroque Architecture](https://www.gentlemansgazette.com/baroque-architecture-guide-explained/)? I also read [this](https://www.gentlemansgazette.com/gothic-architecture-explained-12th-16th-century/).

Comment: This does not seem like a history question. How to classify architectural styles is an architecture question even when referring to buildings constructed in the past.

Comment: If you think Gothic architecture and Baroque architecture are similar you clearly haven't seen either.

Comment: @Semaphore It's also a question of [Art history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_history)

Comment: Seems like the first step would be to compare the two Wikipedia pages and a google image search. Once you've done that, can you explain why the differences are not clear?  I suspect some of the difference has to do with the amount of ornamentation.

Comment: @MarkCWallace Not really - Baroque was highly decorated. It's a difference in **form** more than anything else. Gothic - light, airy, soaring - Baroque - much heavier, grounded, - what Vanbrugh called "the castle air".

Comment: "Crocodiles have 4 legs. Wikipedia says zebras have 4 legs, too. Is there any difference between those two?" Any prior research? You should really take at least a look at photos or some basic text which includes specifics, and go beyond on such vague descriptions as "big cathedrals and beautiful decoration"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer (Edited and expanded)**

A full one would require a book or several.

Gothic architecture was a break from the Romanesque style which preceded it, based on round arches, fat columns, and thick walls or buttresses to bear the downward and outward thrust, and small windows. The pointed arch of the Gothic is more efficient at load-bearing; it also deals better with changes in space - eg a wide nave meeting a narrower transept - since the angle of the arch can be varied without awkward junctions.

This, together with [flying buttresses](http://ignoringfriction.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/flying-buttresses.html?m=1)  enabled Gothic (churches) to rise higher, use slimmer, often clustered, columns and, crucially, permit more window openings. They were open to the Divine light, windows into Heaven.

**1) Rheims Cathedral Interior**

[image: Rheims Cathedral Interior]

When the Renaissance rediscovered Classical Greco-Roman architecture, Gothic was seen as a debased style; the very term "Gothic", suggesting barbarous and uncivilised, was a term of abuse. The "Classical language" of Greco-Roman architecture was revived, influenced by people like [Palladio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Palladio). Classical architecture rejected the flamboyance of the Gothic for restraint, harmony and proportion.

**2) Chiswick House, London**

[image: Chiswick House]

**Finally** we come to the **Baroque**! Baroque used the Classical forms, but in new and innovative ways. (The term "Baroque" originally meant a defective pearl, and came to mean "eccentric, bizarre".) Where Classical architecture is restrained, Baroque is monumental, tectonic: it handles space in a totally new way - colonnades sweep round, facades advance and retreat, mass is piled upon mass.

**3) Blenheim Palace**

[image: Blenheim Palace]

**4) Castle Howard Yorkshire England - Great Hall**

[image: Castle Howard Yorkshire England Great Hall]

If you compare the interior of Rheims Cathedral (1) with the Great Hall at Castle Howard (4) you will see how different they are. Yes, they are both lofty and enclose large spaces, but there the similarities end. Rheims is linear, leading the eye to the sanctuary and High Altar. Castle Howard is self-referential - it is saying "Look at **me**" (not God!) And the actual forms are completely at odds; the Great Hall uses round, Romanesque arches, but built on giant pillars, themselves resting on monumental plinths. The statuary is classical, Romans or psuedo-Romans, not saints or Biblical figures. Yet even these "heroic" figures are dwarfed by the scale of the setting, which is literally awe-inspiring.

Baroque became the architectural language of power - popular in Catholic, absolutist France, largely rejected in Protestant, constitutional Britain, where it was frequently laughed at. [Pope](http://www.britainexpress.com/counties/oxfordshire/houses/Blenheim.htm) famously remarked about Blenheim :-

> *Thanks, sir, cried I, tis very fine,
>   but where do you sleep or where d'ye dine?
>   I find by all you have been telling,
>   that 'tis a house but not a dwelling'*

Pope arguably missed the point. The Baroque was no more about comfort than it was about religion. It was power and magnificence in stone.

Recommended : *50 Architecture Ideas you need to know* Philip Wilkinson London 2010

*(All illustrations from relevant Wikipedia pages.)*